# Line chart using multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I'm facing some difficulty to find an example similar to what I need to implement. I need to generate subplots for each record of a CSV in the following format:

```
Batch process name, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun

Batch process 1 ,10,5,14,2,4,5,2
Batch process 2 ,13,4,11,2,4,5,7
Batch process 3 ,8,5,14,2,4,8,4
Batch process 4 ,0,5,13,2,4,9,9
Batch process 5 ,10,5,14,2,4,10,7
Batch process 6 ,0,5,14,2,4,12,0
...
Batch process ... ,10,5,14,2,14,9,10
...
```

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qizMA.png)

For each process (record in the CSV) I pretend to represent a subplot where Y values are represented by each column of the record (each subplot will have 7 values for Y axis). 
X values should be Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun.

The separation by each subplot is to ensure that each graph has its own scale.

Any suggestions on how to implement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include an example of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I used for the example above - completely hard-coded.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data
colnames=['TIME', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'] 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(96,8),
                  columns=['Batch process 1', 'Batch Process 2', 'Batch Process 3', 'Bath Process 4', 'Batch Proces 5', 'Batch Process 6', '...', 'Batch Process 100'])

# Plotting
df.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, grid=True, title="Batch Process duration (minutes)",
    layout=(4, 3), sharex=True, sharey=False, legend=False,    
    style=['r', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'r'],
    xticks=np.arange(0, len(df), 16))

[ax.legend(loc=1) for ax in plt.gcf().axes]


plt.savefig('plot.png')
```